# Add a view overlay on map view android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-android-api-3

I am using the `MapView` from the Google Map Android SDK in full screen, but I have a requirement to display another transparent full view over the mapview. The overlay displays as expected, however, the map can be controlled (markers can be clicked, map can be moved) despite the overlay being on it.

How can I ensure the overlay prevents the map from being controllable when in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following on your overlay view parent layout.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

Remember you need to place above line on parent layout of overlay view

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making your overlay clickable. Add below code to the `xml` of your overlayview.

`android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

For example I use the following code to add a button to the page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/location_map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#359c5e"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/go"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```